# How do Amazon iOS application live search a product?

Tags: ios, machine-learning, computer-vision, augmented-reality, arkit

I am interested to know how the Amazon iOS application allows searching for a product in live mode:

[Demo](https://i.imgur.com/CPYjU55.gifv)

The app size is 100MB+, which may seem that the app embeds a machine learning model. It also seems non-imaginable that they send the picture data to the server for analyzing while using a live mode approach due to the data cost for the user and latency using the server.

During the search you can see some dots representing shapes/text/surface/closest object, is this enabled by using ARKIT?

If yes, it is only used for the features points animations or does it have a real impact to help to get the object right?

If not, how do they achieve this and for which reason?

Any help to let me see a little bit clearer or a new way to look for would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For AR/VR user experience Amazon uses [Sumerian](https://aws.amazon.com/sumerian/). It is platform-agnostic. Sumerian is built on open web standards and supports both **Apple ARKit** (for iOS apps) and **Google ARCore** (for Android and iOS apps, and web for development), meaning app creators can build one Sumerian app that runs on Android, iOS, Oculus Go, Oculus Rift, HTC Vive, HTC Vive Pro, Google Daydream and Lenovo Mirage.

> **No AR/VR expertise needed**! Amazon Sumerian lets anyone create AR/VR applications. You don’t need specialized programming or 3D graphics expertise to get started. You can create, edit, and publish applications with a web browser using the Sumerian editor. Sumerian has a drag-and-drop app editor and 3D object library, its Visual State Machine for scripting complex automated scenes, and went inside the process of creating AI hosts, which you can have full conversations with inside these virtual experiences.

Touching your **next question**: ARKit and ARCore frameworks exceptionally designed for camera tracking using 6DOF. Any running ARSession (it doesn't matter what: in ARKit or in ARCore) has a session's configuration classes that manage all the things for tracking process, including feature points that you saw in the video. Read about ARKit's [ARWorldTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration) and [ARImageTrackingConfiguration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arimagetrackingconfiguration). Also read about ARCore's [Augmented Images](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/augmented-images/).

Along with 3D tracking, there are image recognition (a.k.a. image detection) techniques as well. Objects in video are processed on AWS Cloud Computing (there's enough power to exploit Amazon AI algorithms within milliseconds).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your precious and detailed answer. If I take your last paragraph. You think that they are capturing every frame or maybe a subset of them (1 per second) and send it to AWS? No ML is done within the application?

Comment: ARKit by default captures 60 fps, ARCore – 30 fps (at the moment). Of course you (as well as Amazon developers) can lower a frame rate till 5 fps or even 1 fps (although 1 fps is not effective). Amazon uses their own cloud computing. So, all ML is done within a cloud. The weakest link in the chain is internet speed in this case.

Comment: Awesome, I see what you mean I see now the way to do it. Thank you very much